# Line integral in complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals, integration-by-parts

I'm doing a course in Complex analysis and found myself struggling with a specific line integral.

Let
$$\gamma (t) \equiv \pi t + (t^2-t)i,\qquad 0 \leq t \leq 1$$

Compute the line integral

$$ \int z \sin z dz$$
over the line $\gamma$.

I know that $dz=(\pi+i(2t-1))dt$, and could insert this and substitute $z=\gamma(t)$. Limits on the integral run from $t=0$ to $t=1$. Then I would have:
$$\int_0^1(\pi t +i(t^2-t))(\sin(\pi t+i(t^2-t))(\pi+i(2t-1))dt$$

I could re-write this in the form $\int u \sin (u) u'$ using integration by parts but what do I do next?

Comment: Well you could instead use the fundamental theorem and evaluate the antiderivative at the endpoints since that function is entire and therefore analytic everywhere

Comment: You can try to do that line integral....and may your favourite gods be with you as it looks nasty and even evil. Or else observe the function is pretty nice and, perhaps, *choose* a different path between $\;0\;$ and $\;\pi\;$ in the complex plane...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the curve you are working on is quite difficult to handle, you could start thinking of the Fundamental Theorem.  Indeed, the function $f(z)=\sin z-z\cos z$ is an antiderivative of $z\sin z$ and the curve gamma connects the points $z=0,~z=\pi$, so:
$$\int_\gamma z\sin zdz=\int_\gamma f'(z)dz=f(\pi)-f(0)=\pi.$$